# missing + sign causes javascript interpreter to go haywire

Tags: javascript

On several occasions, I've encountered a situation where a missing character causes the javascript interpreter to go haywire or give a completely useless error message.  As an example, the following two files differ in exactly two characters (there's a missing plus sign in the second file):

http://phillipmfeldman.org/English/hangman.html

http://phillipmfeldman.org/English/test.html

Tracking such things down can be a huge pain.  Is there any good way to debug such things?

Comment: Install firebug on Firefox?

Comment: Or use the Chrome developer console. It took me right to where the `+` is missing. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string test.html:737` is a good error message.

Comment: I would love to use Chrome, but I've never been able to get it to install on my Windows 7 computer.  "The installer failed to start".

Answer (score 1):

Your error line is:

```
elem.value= score + ' (' + points_received_sum.toFixed(2) + '/' +
    points_possible_sum ')';
```

the error in the console on Chrome says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string test.html:737
```

That's a really clear error. It's not Haywire, it's a helpful error message telling you where the problem is. There's nothing much more that the parser / runtime could do for you.

Comment: I would love to use Chrome, but I've never been able to get it to install on my Windows 7 computer. "The installer failed to start"  IE9, Firefox, and Opera do not provide any indication of the nature of the error or its location.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that Firefox won't show you the location of a syntax error. Did you open the developer tools / JavaScript console? (It's been a while since I've used Firefox, not sure what's available nowadays.)

Comment: @PhillipM.Feldman The answer your problem is how to get proper tools not how to solve this particular case. I suggest asking on superuser.stackexchange.com how to get Chrome or FF installed. You could try installing a virtual machine container (VirtualBox is free) and install a non-Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Internet Explorer.  Its JavaScript debugging output isn't exactly fantastic, and often leads to the wrong lines and locations.  Later versions of IE don't have this problem.

If you have syntax errors (such as missing an operator), then you will have those errors no matter what browser you use.  Give Google Chrome a try to track these down.  It has excellent developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

A lint that you can incorporate into your IDE http://www.javascriptlint.com/

and

http://gruntjs.com/

Comment: JSLint is often overly strict.  I recommend JSHint instead.  http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: @brad - Some of us pay lots of money for things being strict ;->

Comment: Perhaps strict in the wrong word... Let me restate as... JSLint has occasionally led to some less-than-ideal code.  I don't remember the specific example that made me switch to JSHint, but I think it had to do with indenting an object literal on the next line.  It would complain about it, even though the code was more readable, and inline with the standards of the repo I was working in.

Comment: @Brad - I still like strict - Suits me fine and despite the  double entendres, it works.